# Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rethinkdb

I am working with RethinkDB in my android code for realtime database.Some of the external libraries requires the use of Java8. However, when I add Java8 using Jack,Project showing the compilation error. What might be the problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.devendra.demoapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      jackOptions {
         enabled true
     }
  }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
 dexOptions {
    incremental true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })
 compile files('libs/rethinkdb-driver-2.3.3.jar')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: show your error logs

Comment: From the android docs: `Android does not support all Java 8 language features.` (source: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html). Probably this is your issue...

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi is there any solution to use rethinkdb with android studio2.2.3.